# classes with same names

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, namespaces

I have a user model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

end
```

This model is used to store all the corporate users

Then I would like to have another user model inside my workplace namespace:

```
class Workplace::User < ActiveRecord::Base

end
```

This class would be used for the users of my users in their workplace

It doesn't work and rises following error message when I want to migrate:

```
Expected .../app/models/workplace/user.rb to define User
```

I don't have this issue with models using different names but I want to use the same name (makes more sense to me...)

How could I? Thanks!!!

Comment: Personally, I think this is a bad idea, because you'll now have to track which user type you're dealing with across your code. To me it sounds like you have app users, and workplace users. Why not just have AppUser and User? Or use the same model, use appropriate associations, and make the difference(s) go away?

Comment: I can't use the same model as I have a many-to-many relationship. User is the "corporate directory" while Workplace::User is the personal directory of the users working in the workplace. An alternative would have been to keep the class out of the model and to create a WorkplaceUser (or any other name) class but I tried this way because the routing seems to be cleaner. I now have workplace_users_path instead of having workplace_workplace_users_path. But I'm quite new to rails and I'm still searching my way. I'm open to any suggestions...

Comment: Why don't you use Single Table Inheritance? Everything would be much cleaner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you declare classes in a name space, rails expects the files for the MVC to be placed in a folder with the same name as the namespace.

Try placing them in

> app/models/workplace/user.rb
>
> app/controllers/workplace/user_controller.rb
>
> app/views/workplace/

Comment: It is the case. This is done automatically by the scaffold generator

Comment: hmm strange, I tried doing this and I have no problems, you say it fails in rake db:migrate? do you have the correct entries in routes.rb? and could you add the generator commands you tried?

Comment: What I did is placing my other user.rb class in another namespace folder (model/admin instead of model/) and now Workplace::User works. Strange behaviour. Thanks by the way, you put me in the right direction.

Comment: @ndemoreau are you sure it is this issue? I felt that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13236083/rails-class-loading-skips-namespaced-class-when-another-class-of-same-name-in-ro is more likely