# Rails class loading skips namespaced class when another class of same name in root namespace is loaded

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, classloader

I have two namespaces, each with its own controller and presenter classes:
`Member::DocumentsController`
`Member::DocumentPresenter`
`Guest::DocumentsController`
`Guest::DocumentPresenter`

Both presenters inherit from `::DocumentPresenter`.

Controllers access their respective presenters without namespace specified, e.g.:

```
class Guest::DocumentsController < ActionController::Base
    def show
        DocumentPresenter.new(find_document)
    end
end
```

This usually calls presenter within same namespace. However sometimes in development environment I see base ::DocumentPresenter is being used.

I suspect the cause is that base ::DocumentPresenter is already loaded, so Rails class auto-loading doesn't bother to look further. Is this likely the case? Can it happen in production environment too?

I can think of two solutions:

- rename base class to DocumentPresenterBase
- explicitly require appropriate presenter files in controller files

Is there a better solution?

Comment: If you're `show` method inside `Guest::DocumentsController` will only ever work with the `Guest::DocumentPresenter` it'd be simplest to specify the namespace when calling it's `new` method.

Comment: @Deefour haha yes I forgot about the most obvious one - thanks. I'll wait for a while for a perfect solution, which would not make me add characters all over my source files.

Comment: AFAIK Rails only preloads Models in `production` so this should happen in production too (but I couldn't find actual documentation on this ATM).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct in your assumptions - If you do not specify namespace, Ruby starts from current namespace and works its way up to find the class, and because the namespaced class is not autoloaded yet, the `::DocumentPresenter` is found and autoloader does not trigger.

**As a solution** I would recommend renaming `::DocumentPresenter` to `DocumentPresenterBase`, because this protects you from bugs when you forget namespacing or explicit requiring somewhere.

The **second option** to consider would actually be using specific namespaced classnames all over the place, but this suffers from bugs when you accidentally forget to namespace some call.

```
class Guest::DocumentsController < ActionController::Base
  def show
    Guest::DocumentPresenter.new(find_document)
  end
end
```

**Third option** would be your second - explicitly require all the classes in initializer beforehand. I have done this with Rails API which receives embedded models in `JSON` and Rails tends to namespace them when the actual models are not loaded yet.

**Option 3.5** You could probably trick autoloader to do the heavy lifting (though, this might seem more like a hack):

```
class Guest::DocumentsController < ActionController::Base

  # trigger autoload
  Guest::DocumentPresenter

  def show
    # This should refer Guest::DocumentPresenter
    DocumentPresenter.new(find_document)
  end

  def show
    # As will this
    DocumentPresenter.new(find_document)
  end
end
```

Still the cleanest would be to rename the base class.

Answer (score 1):

I think in 3 solutions if you want to mantein the name, one is your second solution.

1) explicitly require appropriate presenter files in controller files

2) Execute the full environment class path, like:

```
class Guest::DocumentsController < ActionController::Base
    def show
        Guest::DocumentPresenter.new(find_document)
    end
end
```

3) Create a file on initialize directory and execute require manually (the worst options :S)