# Namespaces and inheritance in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an engine called Admin and a few controllers.

```
# admin/app/controllers/admin/application_controller.rb
module Admin
  class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  end
end

# admin/app/controllers/admin/foo_controller.rb
module Admin
  class CardsController < ApplicationController
  end
end

# app/controllers/application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
end
```

If I visit my main app and THEN /admin the `CardsController` inherits from `ApplicationController` NOT `Admin::ApplicationController`. If I first visit /admin and then the main app it works.

I guess that when we first visit the main app the constant `ApplicationController` is created, which is then found and used when visiting /admin instead of loading `Admin::ApplicationController`.

How can one avoid this issue?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails class loading skips namespaced class when another class of same name in root namespace is loaded](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13236083/rails-class-loading-skips-namespaced-class-when-another-class-of-same-name-in-ro)

Answer (score 4):

You'll have to be specific about which class you are inheriting from:

```
module Admin
  class CardsController < Admin::ApplicationController
    # ...
  end
end
```